# nvidia black screen at lightdm when switching from intel to nvidia gpu

Tags: nvidia, cuda, 15.10, primus

Nvidia Prime and graphics switching is broken for me.

I can use my Intel graphics fine, but if I try and switch to Nvidia it just shows a black lightdm screen.  I know it boots because I can hear the greeter sound.

I tried changing the resolution before I switched and still a black screen.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

I am just trying to use CUDA honestly and don't need to switch if I can just use CUDA.

./devicequery returns nothing when in Intel graphics mode so I figured I had to get into Nvidia graphics mode.﻿

Using 352 with CUDA 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for 2 days I figured out why it wasn't working.

I should mention I installed CUDA 7.5 and that also installs Nvidia drivers 352.  I also have a fresh copy of 14.04.3 installed and only updated before installing those CUDA drivers from Nvidias website.

After looking at the Xorg log I found GLX wasn't loading.  I learned that first a kernel module gets loaded and then GLX and then something like LibGL.  To fix the GLX issue I installed a few packages.

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
```

After doing that everything worked to my surprise.  I have no idea why this isn't installed in the process, but I reported the bug to Nvidia either way.

I'm just starting messing around with CUDA, but it seems like this shouldn't of took 2 days to get working.